# try_files directive for multiple grav installations

Tags: nginx, grav

At first I installed grav to a sub-level directory of a nginx server and it works fine: [cadoankitovua.com/blog](http://cadoankitovua.com/blog)

The conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cadoankitovua.com www.cadoankitovua.com *.cadoankitovua.com;
    root /home/grav/web/public/;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /opt/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

I, then, installed an identical copy of grav to the /text directory and tried to modify the conf file in many different ways that I know of. None works.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I edit the conf file to make grav work on both /blog and /text directories?
2. In general, how do I make many (>2) installations of grav work if I install them in many sub-level directories?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about grav, but you might start by adding a `location /text` block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cadoankitovua.com www.cadoankitovua.com *.cadoankitovua.com;
    root /home/grav/web/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string;
    }
    location /text {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /text/index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /opt/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

EDIT: A general solution would use a named location with a rewrite statement, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+) $1/index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string last;
    rewrite ^ /blog/index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string last;
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing (w/o **/text**) I tried and it did not work. Now I saw your version :) I just tried it. It works like a charm. Thank you. How about the second question?

Comment: So far the general one would work with 2 original /blog and /text. I added /foo and /bar. these 2 new one won't work. I deleted 2 new one and changed name /text to /foo or /foo1. They would work. I have to try more of different combinations to make sense of it. I will report here more. :) Thanks. Many thanks :)

Comment: I interpret the regex `^(/[^/]+)` as: Start with one slash, then followed by one or more of any character but slash. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. And the only URI that will not match the first `rewrite` will be a solitary `/`, which will cause the second `rewrite` to be executed.

Comment: So what would happen if there isn't the second `rewrite`?

Comment: It would probably result in a 404, as it's basically still looking for `$document_root$uri`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135909/discussion-between-ngungo-and-richard-smith).